# Access SQL database another computer

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

My sql connection and server work in my program only on my PC. However, if i try and run the program on a school computer this does not work. How do i connect my school computer to the same SQL server/database used on my computer.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: If it doesn't work then you did it wrong. We can't know what you did wrong if we can't see what you did. Show us the code. That's not something we should have to ask. ALWAYS provide ALL the relevant information.

Comment: Also, *"this does not work"* is NEVER an adequate description of what happens. The details of what actually happens is also ALWAYS part of the relevant information.

Comment: BTW, in this case, "the code" would almost certainly include the connection string.

Comment: You would need a way of connecting to your (presumably) home computer over the Internet. It is a Bad Idea to expose a database to the Internet, so you would need some sort of web-based API on the home computer, and to setup your router to forward the appropriate port to your computer. **Or** you could backup the DB at home and restore it to an instance of SQL Server at school.